# How to solve this listview problem: not all code is executed

Tags: android

I have this 3 lines of code which I use to hold the state of items in my listview when scrolling, but my problem is, the last line of code only gets executed. This is the code block:

```
holder.viewName.setTextColor((priority.equals("Low")? Color.BLUE: Color.GRAY ) );
holder.viewName.setTextColor((priority.equals("Medium")? Color.GREEN: Color.GRAY ) );
holder.viewName.setTextColor((priority.equals("High")? Color.RED: Color.GRAY ) ); // items in this state condition only gets executed in the listview, the rest are ignored and set to gray.
```

Is there a way I can join the code logic together, so that all 3 conditions can be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3 lines get executed, but you're always overriding the text color with the next line. Use a condition instead:

```
if (priority.equals("Low")) {
   holder.viewName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
} else if (priority.equals("Medium")) {
   holder.vieName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else if (priority.equals("High")) {
   holder.viewName.setTextCOlor(Color.RED);
} else {
   holder.viewName.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
}
```

Edit: Switch statements for strings is not yet availalbe in Java right?

Comment: I never manage to do anything with the switch in java, its so limited that I always do else if lol-Correct answer, you posted faster than me

Comment: i tried doing that, but then the listview starts behaving oddly with item colors getting copied to different rows that don't require it.

Comment: sorry about that. i think it works now, i will have to do more test just to be sure about it and keep you posted if you don't mind. thank you once again

Comment: np. This code solves your problem from above. If it still not work, I think it has to be wrong somewhere else.

Comment: yeah it works correctly now. thanks once again. i have another question, but i guess i will start another thread for that.

Answer (score 1):

first I would use equalsIgnoreCase because there is nothing more frustrating than losing hours looking for a case sensitive error ^^

You problem is that your code is limited to the last statement

```
holder.viewName.setTextColor((priority.equals("High")? Color.RED: Color.GRAY ) );
```

what happens when the case of low or medium is that they are set at the right color then arrives the test of high that switches it back to gray

you want to change you code to a switch or else if statement.

```
color = Color.GRAY;

if (priority.equals("Low")) {
    color = Color.BLUE;
} else if (priority.equals("Medium")) {
    color = Color.GREEN;
} else if (priority.equals("High")) {
    color = Color.RED;
}

holder.viewName.setTextColor(color);
```

Finally the you don't need the ternair here (condition)?val1:val2

it is not a bad idea with 2 colors, but with 4 it looses interst

Comment: thanks for your input. pity, i can't mark two answers at once.

Comment: Don't worry about that, Roflcoptr answered the same as me but faster, the only reason I  left my answer is that I wanted to point out a couple of other things :D